# From video to image in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Given a video (of arbitrary lenght in a format supported by the device) taken from the gallery, how can I extract the first frame as an EncodedImage? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the only way to do that is through native code. Historically some platforms didn't support grabbing a video frame and we didn't revisit that over the past 7 years. You can file an RFE on this but right now I'm not sure when we'll get around to implementing it as media is painful.

Comment: For the readers: I just published a CN1Lib that allows to do what I asked here, https://github.com/jsfan3/CN1Libs-VideoOptimizer

Comment: This apparently does not work on the simulator